# How do I serve a directory as a virtual block device?

Tags: filesystems

I want a tool that scans a directory and exposes it as a seekable read-only filesystem image. Querying blocks from that virtual block device should cause opening files on host filesystem. It may assume that all exposed files are not modified during operation.

I remember seeing description of such tool (probably intended to allow easy sharing of a host directory into VM), but I don't remember how it is called or which filesystem it mimics (probably ext4 or iso9660 or fat). Maybe it's a part of some virtualization software package. One of answers [hinted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615319/17594) that it's part of QEMU.

Obviously, it should not result in actually reading all the files or creating non-sparse temporary file holding all the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Qemu can do that for VMs](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/images.html#virtual-fat-disk-images) but other than that, I've no idea.

Comment: Yes, that's what I remember seeing.